# Excel Formula Series of #'s and Sequence

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need a formula that uses a series of numbers in one column (numbers 1-21) and returns just a number for every 21 cells.

Example: for every 21 cells return a 1 for every 21 cells return a 2 for every 21 cells return a 3. This should happen up to 650 cells

My formulas do not do this properly, I have to keep changing the # for the formula to work the way I want just looking for a faster solution. This is the formula I am using (=$B$42+2)

[image: Excel Capture]

Comment: so you want to start at 1 and add one to the number every 21 rows?

Comment: or do you want to start with what is in B42 and increment by 1 every 21 rows?

Comment: It would help if you could make the line and row reference visible in your example, if you could add a column with the expected result and if we could know on which cell the formula you are describing is entered.

Comment: In the 1 Column the numbers should be a series of 1-21 in the second column every 21 calls should be 1 then it should repeat with 2 then with 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the first column first cell:

```
=MOD(ROW(A1)-1,21)+1
```

and this in the second column first cell:

```
=INT((ROW(A1)-1)/21)+1
```

And copy both formula down the desired number of rows

---

If one has the Dynamic array formula SEQUENCE() replace the `ROW(A1)-1` with `SEQUENCE(650,,0)` and Excel will spill the values down automatically 650 rows.

[image]

Comment: @DominiqueB if this worked for you please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think is easier you put a filter above the column and filter, for example, the number 1, and put SUM() in the ones, that way you will know how many times go 21 times.
My question is, the column always goes 1-21 or have other numbers if you have other numbers you can put one column that repeats 1-21 in till the end and filter the same way I said before and later you can hide the column.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In the 1 Column the numbers should be a series of 1-21 in the second column every 21 calls should be 1 then it should repeat with 2 then with 3